# What places other than sys.path python looks for when importing a package

Tags: python, package, pythonpath, name-collision

#### Scenario

From a package let's say `beta`:
After modifying the `sys.path`, importing a package `alpha` then reverting the `sys.path`. I try to  import a module `data_provider` that exists in both `alpha` and `beta`

**The issue is:** the `data_provider` in `alpha` gets picked over `beta` even though sys.path now has no traces of `alpha`'s directories

**Question:** Is that a bug, or there's some other places than `sys.path` (may be caches) that python looks at when trying to import a module

#### Code

```py
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"src"))

sys.path.insert(0, '../alpha')
import alpha
sys.path.remove('../alpha')

import data_provider as dp

print(sys.path)
print(dp.__file__)
```

The full codebase could be found [here](https://github.com/weshouman/tut-py-package-link/blob/absolute-import/beta/beta.py)

Comment: when you imported `alpha` all the modules that were present in the `alpha.__init__.py` file were imported and cached in `sys.modules`. Now `data_provided` will be imported from `sys.module` if it was earlier present in `alpha` otherwise it will look according to paths present in  `sys.path`.

Comment: do you know what is the cleanest way to invalidate the caches of all `alpha`'s modules? I've tried to reload the imported modules, but unfortunately, reloading doesn't result in having all the members of `beta`'s `data_provider` defined, only the common one `get_tests()` could be found but not `get_products()`

Comment: you've only presented the problem but what's your end goal?

Comment: I would like to be able to call other packages using absolute import in a clean way, taking into consideration that, due to similar design patterns, some module names collide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first place checked during import search is `sys.modules`. This
> mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been previously
> imported, including the intermediate paths. So if `foo.bar.baz` was
> previously imported, `sys.modules` will contain entries for `foo`,
> `foo.bar`, and `foo.bar.baz`. Each key will have as its value the
> corresponding module object.
>
> During import, the module name is looked up in `sys.modules` and if
> present, the associated value is the module satisfying the import, and
> the process completes. However, if the value is `None`, then a
> `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised. If the module name is missing, Python
> will continue searching for the module.

Read more about it here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache.